# adding 1 day to yyyyMMdd date format in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like  below

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['20220725']], ['report_date'])

df.show()
+-----------+
|report_date|
+-----------+
|   20220725|
+-----------+
```

Now I want to add one day to the above column value

expected result

```
+----------+
|new_date_1|
+----------+
|  20220726|
+----------+
```

I have tried like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

Convert above `yyyyMMdd` column to `yyyy-MM-dd` format

```
convert_df = df.withColumn("new_date", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(f.col("report_date"), 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))

convert_df.show()
+-----------+----------+
|report_date|  new_date|
+-----------+----------+
|   20220725|2022-07-25|
+-----------+----------+
```

Add one day to the column and then convert back to `yyyyMMdd` format

```
posting_df = convert_df.withColumn("new_posting_date", f.date_add(f.col("new_date"), 1)).withColumn("new_date_1", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(f.col("new_posting_date"), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyMMdd'))

posting_df.show()
+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
|report_date|  new_date|new_posting_date|new_date_1|
+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
|   20220725|2022-07-25|      2022-07-26|  20220726|
+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
```

I am able to achieve what I want but want to see if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main possible improvement I see is using `to_date` and `date_format` instead of `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime`.

Example code

```py
df.withColumn("new_date",
  f.date_format(
    f.date_add(f.to_date(df.report_date, "yyyyMMdd"), 1),
    "yyyyMMdd"
  )
)
```

Link to documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date